# discrete_log in elliptic curve torsion basis using sage

Tags: elliptic-curves, sagemath, discrete-logarithms

I want to solve a discrete log problem on elliptic curve using sagemath. Given a basis of E[D], denoted as P and Q. How to solve a*P + b*Q = R where R is a point of order D.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Also asked at https://ask.sagemath.org/question/71217/discrete-log-in-two-dimension/, which I think is a more appropriate site for this question.